# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) problem with dpkg?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I wanted to install `arm-none-eabi-gcc` and I have encountered the above error. I know that the problem is generic and I need to read lines above that message but after analyzing error lines I still do not know what to do to solve that issue. Here are error lines maybe anyone would be able to help me.

```
Unpacking gdb-arm-none-eabi (7.6.50.20131218-0ubuntu1+1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gdb-arm-none-eabi_7.6.50.20131218-0ubuntu1+1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/gdb.1.gz', which is also in package gdb 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gdb-arm-none-eabi_7.6.50.20131218-0ubuntu1+1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug on LaunchPad for this [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdb-arm-none-eabi/+bug/1320305), there's been a work around suggested in [comment #4](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdb-arm-none-eabi/+bug/1320305/comments/4) which is.

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install gdb-arm-none-eabi`
```